# an error in function definition won't be detected in Python?

Tags: python, grammar

Here is a python module,

```
#a.py

def bar():
    print x  #x not defined, apparently will result in an error

def foo():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

The above module can be run (`$ python a.py`) without any error. Why? Just because `bar` is not used in `__main__`?

But `bar`'s definition is executed, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `bar`'s definition is executed, but the definition doesn't contain an error. It is valid Python to define a function that refers to globals that don't yet exist, so long as they exist when the function is called. Consider this:

```
def bar():
    print x

x = 10
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar()
```

This does not result in an error. And this is only sensible, since even if `x` exists at the time the function is defined, there is nothing to stop you using `del` on it later. The point when `x` needs to be defined is when `bar` is called (if ever), not when `bar` is defined.

If Python did work the way you are suggesting, then it would be impossible to define mutually recursive functions without weird hacks like temporarily binding one name to `None`, then defining both functions.

**EDIT:** To elaborate on Ignacio's answer to the Alcott's question in the comments, yes syntax errors are caught before the function can be executed, but they're actually caught before it can be defined either.

When Python loads a file, it parses the entire contents into statements and then executes the statements one at a time. A syntax error means it was unable to successfully figure out what statements the file contains, so it can't execute *anything*. So the error will occur when the file is loaded, which means either when you directly run it with the interpreter, or when you `import` it.

This pre-processing step is known as "compile time", even though Python is not normally thought of as a compiled language; it is technically compiled to a byte code format, but this is almost entirely uninteresting because the byte code pretty much just directly represents the source code statements.

Comment: Clear answer. :-). And if `bar`'s definition contains some syntax error, then the syntax error will be detected when the definition is executed, right?

Comment: @Alcott: I've added a section giving a bit more detail on your syntax error question.

Answer (score 1):

Python resolves name lookups at runtime.

```
def bar():
  print x

x = 3
bar()
```

Comment: Global var `x` needn't to be defined before the definition of `bar`, rignt?

Comment: It needn't be defined at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that the *definition* of `bar` is executed when you run the script. However, Python can't determine whether a global variable named `x` actually exists until the whole script is run.

For example, you could do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        x = 5
    foo()
```

The compiler wouldn't be able to determine at *compile* time whether `x` is going to exist or not.

Comment: So, as long as there is a global var named `x` is defined right before the call to `bar()`, then no error will be thrown, right?

Comment: That's right. But you must keep in mind that this is a *runtime* decision.